# Have to click twice on Dash button for callback with multiple outputs

Tags: python-3.x, button, callback, plotly-dash

**TL;DR**: Download caused by button callback in python3 Dash application only starts after second click. Not at the first..

**Full**: I am quite new to building web applications with Dash in Python3.8 and I would like to have my app download an excel file after clicking a button. Ideally when the download starts the button has to show the `success` color as well. Hence I am using multiple `Output` with the `n_clicks` as `Input`. With the underlying piece of code I get the following behavior of my application:

1. 1st click: button turns green (`success`) - **no** download starts
2. 2nd click: now the download starts (or the download window opens) - button stays green
3. 2> clicks: download window opens every click, button stays green (or refreshes, not sure)

This is not the behavior I expected, I would like to start the download after the first click already! I have this piece of code in my dash layout:

```
html.Div(
  id="select-upload-form",
  style={
    "width": "100%",
    "marginBottom": "1rem",
    "justifyContent": "center",
    "alignItems": "center",
    "verticalAlign": "middle",
    "textAlign": "center",
  },
  children=[
    dbc.Button(
      "Download the upload form",
      id="download-excel",
      color="secondary",
      external_link="true",
      target="",
      href="",
    ),
  ],
),
```

and the following callback:

```
@app.callback(
    [
        Output("download-excel", "href"),
        Output("download-excel", "color"),
        Output("download-excel", "target"),
    ],
    [Input("download-excel", "n_clicks")],
)
def download_excel_file(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks:
        excelfile = write_excel_file()  # creates an excel file using Pandas
        excelfile.seek(0)
        media_type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        data = base64.b64encode(excelfile.read()).decode("utf-8")
        href_data = f"data:{media_type};base64,{data}"

        return href_data, "success", href_data,
    else:
        return None, "secondary", None
```

Answer (score 0):

When the button clicked for the first time,

> target=""

will be replaced by

> target="some_url_from_callback"

and color will be set to "success" etc/

And the button will work if you click it again.

It would work as you expected if you

1. implement the "downlaod" inside of the callback
   or
2. Trigger the callback before use click on the button and set the "target"